# Mysql statement for finding events in the last day

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a mysql PDO statement to select all of the failed logins that have occurred in the last day. My table has 4 columns...id (just auto increments to make distinct entries), ip (char 15), failed (boolean), firstattempt (timestamp). When I add firstattempt>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) in, it starts return false. Without that in the WHERE clause, it does return the number of lines. Any ideas?

```
function logip()
{
global $db;
global $user;
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
var_dump($ip);

$sql=$db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(failed) FROM logins WHERE firstattempt>=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY), ip=:ip');
$sql->execute(array(':ip'=>$ip));
$num=$sql->fetchColumn();

//$row=$sql->fetch();

var_dump($num);
    $sql=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO logins (ip, failed, firstattempt) VALUES (:ip, :failed, :firstattempt)');
    if ($user->authenticated())
        $sql->execute(array(':ip'=>$ip, ':failed'=>false, ':firstattempt'=>time()));
    else
        $sql->execute(array(':ip'=>$ip, ':failed'=>true, ':firstattempt'=>time()));
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to put php as a tag in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATE_SUB function.

```
SELECT COUNT(failed) 
FROM   logins 
WHERE  firstattempt>=DATE_SUB(Curdate(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
       AND ip = :ip
```

There were some errors in your sql,

1. WHERE conditions can not be separated by `,`. I think it should be `AND`